# extracting icons from files/folders java

Tags: java, icons

I am trying to extract icons images from specific files or directory using Java. I have looked around the internet but haven't found a reasonable answer to this question. Are there any libraries which would help me achieve this?

thanks, 
TC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can this help ?

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0439.html

Comment: is it some how possible to get bigger icons

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple actually, you just need to use:

- [`URL Class#getResource(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), or
- [`InputStream Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

For an example, check out [How to Use Icons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).